# How to move this bar in Gnome (classic) to the top?

Tags: gnome

How can I remove the bar at the bottom. It shows open windows and tabs. How can I have it on the menu bar at the top instead? This is Gnome classic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and right click on the panel or panel items, you can edit the panel, remove it, or move items to the other panel, as you would have done in Gnome 2.